# Select only records with linked records

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I am seeking a way in mySQL to select only records that have corresponding records in a linked table. I am likely suffering tunnel vision, or otherwise missing something simple.

I have the following query which currently works besides this requirement above:

```
SELECT P.ID, P.NAME, P.SEO_NAME, CI.City, R.Region, C.Country
FROM PROPERTIES P 
LEFT JOIN Cities CI ON P.CITY_ID = CI.CityId
LEFT JOIN Regions R ON P.REGION_ID = R.RegionID
LEFT JOIN Countries C ON P.COUNTRY_ID = C.CountryId 
WHERE APPROVED = '1' AND REGION_ID = '5400' 
ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1;
```

This is related to a previous question of mine, here: [Select rows Having Count in linked table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6698401/mysql-select-rows-having-count-in-linked-table)

While the answer in this linked thread worked for me at the time, I now require the additional information in the query above. Is there any way I can limit it so that only records with records in the linked table `PROPERTY_PHOTOS PP` (which links `ON P.ID = PP.PROPERTY_ID`)

Thanks in advance for any input.

Comment: You're not linking the PROPERTY_PHOTOS table.  If you update your query, I'll fix my answer.

Comment: Thanks to everyone for pointing out the elephant I wasn't seeing. Heh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One more `JOIN`, but not `LEFT`

```
SELECT ...
FROM PROPERTIES P
...
INNER JOIN PROPERTY_PHOTOS PP ON P.ID = PP.PROPERTY_ID
```

or just

```
SELECT ...
FROM PROPERTIES P
...
JOIN PROPERTY_PHOTOS PP ON P.ID = PP.PROPERTY_ID
```

because [they are the same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/565620/difference-between-join-and-inner-join).

Comment: What's the point of this? First comment on my answer that it's not correct, and then post the exact same thing?

Comment: abatischev was actually the first answer I tried, and it immediately worked. OF COURSE it is that simple. I was just looking at this an entirely different way. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Try using INNER JOIN instead of LEFT JOIN.
According to the SQL specifications for [INNER JOIN](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp):

```
The INNER JOIN keyword return rows when there is at least one match in both tables.
```

For the [LEFT JOIN](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp), this becomes:

```
The LEFT JOIN keyword returns all rows from the left table (table_name1), 
even if there are no matches in the right table (table_name2).
```

Comment: @abatishchev: And that's exactly what INNER JOIN does: exclude missing links

Answer (score 4):

An `INNER JOIN` should do this for you:

```
INNER JOIN PROPERTY_PHOTOS PP ON P.ID = PP.PROPERTY_ID
```

This will only return records where there is a match in both tables.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT P.ID, P.NAME, P.SEO_NAME, CI.City, R.Region, C.Country
FROM PROPERTIES P 
LEFT JOIN Cities CI ON P.CITY_ID = CI.CityId
LEFT JOIN Regions R ON P.REGION_ID = R.RegionID
LEFT JOIN Countries C ON P.COUNTRY_ID = C.CountryId 
**INNER JOIN PROPERTY_PHOTOS PP ON P.ID = PP.PROPERTY_ID**
WHERE APPROVED = '1' AND REGION_ID = '5400' 
ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 3):

You will need an "INNER JOIN".

Answer (score -1):

Note: This query doesn't actually include a photos table, but I will assume you are joining it as PP

```
SELECT P.ID, P.NAME, P.SEO_NAME, CI.City, R.Region, C.Country
FROM PROPERTIES P 
LEFT JOIN Cities CI ON P.CITY_ID = CI.CityId
LEFT JOIN Regions R ON P.REGION_ID = R.RegionID
LEFT JOIN Countries C ON P.COUNTRY_ID = C.CountryId 
WHERE APPROVED = '1' AND REGION_ID = '5400' AND PP.PROPERTY_ID IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1;
```